# 'df' command doesn't show file system requested in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: df

This strange behavior begins a few day ago. This is df of all file system

```
michele@OptiPlex-360:~$ df
File system    1K-blocchi    Usati Disponib. Uso% Montato su
udev              1974808        8   1974800   1% /dev
tmpfs              397120     1340    395780   1% /run
/dev/sda1        45225008 14448892  28455736  34% /
none                    4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                 5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
none              1985596       80   1985516   1% /run/shm
none               102400       68    102332   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6       190822060 65912468 115193268  37% /media/volume1
```

Now I ask for sda1 and it gives me a wrong answer

```
michele@OptiPlex-360:~$ df /dev/sda1
File system    1K-blocchi Usati Disponib. Uso% Montato su
udev              1974808     8   1974800   1% /dev
```

instead sda6 works

```
michele@OptiPlex-360:~$ df /dev/sda6
File system    1K-blocchi    Usati Disponib. Uso% Montato su
/dev/sda6       190822060 65912468 115193268  37% /media/volume1
```

Well, what's wrong?

Ah, same issue I have on my other PC with same Ubuntu installed.

Additional output as muru asked for:

```
michele@OptiPlex-360:~$ mount | grep /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
michele@OptiPlex-360:~$ df /
File system                                            1K-blocchi    Usati Disponib. Uso% Montato su
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2438603c-1bfd-4e79-9f6c-ad6575988aee   45225008 14448908  28455720  34% /
```

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the output of `mount | grep /dev/sda1` and `df /`, please.

Answer (score 3):

My personal explanation to this effect is the following: `df` reads `/proc/self/mountinfo` file but doesn't find `/dev/sda1` there.

I know it reads `/proc/self/mountinfo` because when I do `strace df /dev/sda1` I get the following line in the output

```
open("/proc/self/mountinfo", O_RDONLY)  = 3
```

Now, if we examine that file, `/dev/sda` is not there, but it does find `/dev/sdb` there, which explains correct reports for those partitions.

```
================
xieerqi:
$ grep 'sda' /proc/self/mountinfo                                              

================
xieerqi:
$ grep 'sdb' /proc/self/mountinfo                                              
43 22 8:18 / /media/WINDOWS rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime - fuseblk /dev/sdb2 rw,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
49 22 8:21 / /media/xieerqi/0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime - ext4 /dev/sdb5 rw,data=ordered
```

Why it's not there ? I don't know. I can only provide what I've found.

But why does it report `udev` in the output ? `df` looks at filesystems, and `/dev/sda1` is under `/dev` folder, which is where `udev` virtual filesystem is mounted. It's the same behavior if we'd call `df FILE`, like `df /home` or `df /media/MYWINDOWSPARTITION/RANDOMFILE.txt`

I would suggest reporting it as a bug or at least ask the GNU developers about this behavior (copied from man page )

```
REPORTING BUGS
       Report df bugs to bug-coreutils@gnu.org
       GNU coreutils home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
       General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
       Report df translation bugs to <http://translationproject.org/team/>
```

**Edit**

In addition, the `df /` behavior is explained again by `/proc/self/mountinfo` file having the following entry

```
22 0 8:1 / / rw,noatime,nodiratime - ext4 /dev/disk/by-uuid/86df21bf-d95f-435c-9
292-273bdbcba056 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

The root filesystem itself is mounted as `/dev/dis/by-uuid/ACTUAL-UUID-NUMBER.`

But I don't have explanation for `df` with no arguments reporting `/dev/sda1` rather than the path to disk by uuid. Probably the reason is because `/dev/dis/by-uuid/ACTUAL-UUID-NUMBER`  itself is a symlink to `/dev/sda1`, so it resolves it fully without arguments, but with arguments needs to search `/proc/self/mountinfo` file

Answer (score 0):

That's normal (for the second output)   as partitions are mounted by their uuid, not using device names (that's the older style)
Some Linux distributions use the old style and some use the new ones.
Here is a note to better explain the issue [mount partitions by uuid](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/an-easier-way-to-mount-disks-in-linux-by-uuid/)

This mechanism protects against changing disk drive order of you swap disks inside your hardware. If you want,  you can easily change this by specifying the device name in /etc/fstab.

Comment: All my partitions are mounted using UUIDs, but `df -h /dev/sdXY` works as intended.